# How to track QR code scanning when someone scans QR?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, zxing, android-developer-api

Can notifications be sent to the application that generated the QR code when it is scanned by any QR scanner app? I am interested in understanding the logic behind this functionality. Several websites, such as [https://qrfy.com](https://qrfy.com/), offer a feature where the scan count is automatically updated on their site when a user scans their QR code, without accessing the encoded URL.

I have searched a lot but can't find any solution. Has anyone tried this approach?

Comment: QR codes only contain data there is not channel back to the creator. The only way to monitor QR code scannings is by replacing the contained URL contained in the QR code. My guess this service simply works like an URL shortener, but you get thes hort URL as QR code with some eye candy and not as text. If the someone scans the URL and accesses the contained web site you can track the users before you redirect them the the target URL.